# Time series clustering of activity of machines

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cluster-analysis

I have a NxM matrix where N is the number of time intervals and M are the number of nodes in a graph.

Each cell indicates the nodes that were active in that time interval

Now I need to find group of nodes that always appear together across time series. Is there some approach I can use to cluster these nodes together based on their time series activity.

Answer (score 0):

In R you could do this:

```
# hierarchical clustering

library(dendextend)     # contains color_branches()
dist_ts <- dist(mydata) # calculate distances
hc_dist <- hclust(dist_ts)
dend_ts <- as.dendrogram(hc_dist)
# set some value for h (height within the dendrogram) here that makes sense for you
dend_100 <- color_branches(dend_ts, h = 100) 
plot(dend_100)
```

This creates a dendrogram with colored branches. 
You could do much better visualizations, but your post is pretty generic (somewhat unclear what you're asking) and you didn't indicate whether you like R at all.

Answer (score 0):

As the sets may *overlap* most clustering methods will not produce optimum results.

Instead, treat each time point as a transaction, containing all active nodes as items. Then run **frequent itemset mining** to find frequently active sets of machines.